# CS50 (2020) PSET6 DNA IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, cs50

This has been a very difficult problem set for me, and I've had a tough time even getting something to work.  At this time this is what my code looks like; I can't even tell if it outputs anything because I can't get it to run without an error.

```
import csv
from cs50 import get_string
from sys import argv

if len(argv) != 3:
    print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
    exit()

# Load Dictionary into the system
with open(argv[1], 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    dna_data = list(reader)
    str_names = (dna_data[0][1:])

# Load Text DNA Sequence into system
text = open(argv[2], 'r')
sequence = text.read()
linecount = 0

# occurrences of each str in dna sequence
occurrences = []
for i in range(0,len(str_names)):
    start = 0
    substr_count = 0
    consecutive = 0
    while True:
        string = sequence
        substring = str(dna_data[i])
        location = string.find(substring,start)
        if location == -1:
            break
        if location != start:
            consecutive = 1
        else:
            consecutive += 1
        if consecutive > substr_count:
            substr_count = consecutive
        start = location + len(substring)
    occurrences.append(substr_count)
    substr_count = 0

repeats = []
match = 0
name = 0
for i in range (1, len(dna_data)):
    for j in range (1, len(dna_data[i])):
        repeats.append(dna_data[i][j])
    for k in range(1, len(dna_data)):
        if int(repeats[k]) == int(occurrences[k]): # THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
            match += 1
            nomatch = False
        else:
            nomatch = True
    if match == len(occurrences) and nomatch == False:
        print(dna_data[i][0])
        name += 1
    else:
        nomatch = True
        match = 0
if nomatch == True and name == 0:
    print("No Match")
```

I am sure the answer is probably something simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out.  I am pretty sure the list length of both "occurrences" and "repeats" are, in fact, both "len(dna_data)," but the error seems to state that k is increasing past the length of one of the lists.  Is there anything here that is obviously causing a problem?  How could I go about comparing the number present at position k within the repeats list and occurrences list? Thanks.

Comment: You could try to use the python debugger to print both lists before the error raising. Use from ipdb import set_trace then put before the error line set_trace() run the code and print both lists and their lengths to check which is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for that, I got my code to function thanks to debugging this way.  I am now having problems with my code working appropriately, but at least it runs now.  I am very close to getting this to work.